# background doesn't stay fixed when I add video header -chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Please see background effect here: https://jsfiddle.net/xorkme75/embedded/result/

background is `fixed` here. so when you scroll the page, you can see rest of the image. for example scroll down and you can see the lady's face.

Works both chrome and firefox.

*

But when I add video to header. This effect not working in chrome anymore. Here is example (please see in chrome): http://areafordemos.net63.net/chrome.html

**How did I broke it?**

I added to CSS:

```
#video-container {  
    top: 10%;
    width:100%;
    height:70%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:-1; 
    }

video.fillWidth {
    width:100%;
    }
```

and I added to HTML:

```
<div id="video-container">
    <video autoplay muted loop paused class="fillWidth">
        <source src="xhttp://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm"/>
        Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>
</div><!-- end video-container -->
```

CSS Code of broken area:

```
.dzen_bg {
background-image: url('http://seventhqueen.com/themes/kleo/sensei-e-learning/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2015/06/hero16.jpg'); 
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: 100% 12px; 
background-attachment: fixed;
padding-top: 10px; 
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

When I delete `width: 100%;` from `video.fillWidth` for example effect is back but video doesn't look like I want. So I am literally stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `z-index:-2;` to `.dzen_bg`. Because I see you have `z-index:-1;` on `#video-container`. I guess it will fix yout problem.

Comment: Beautiful solution. But occurs another problem right now. I can't hover the inside of that `div` anymore. Doesn't respond to mouse moves.

Comment: @Rough make another div without `background-color`, with `z-index: 0` or more, and then you can hover on it, and make some changes in `.dzen-bg`

Comment: @AleshaOleg, now background doesn't change when I scroll. But It changes after scroll+hover. What a puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

You have `height: 70%` in `#video-container`, if you remove it will work fine. And add this height to `video.fillWidth`

Comment: Yes, effect is back when I delete `height: 70%`, but how I will set video height right now? It is covering the whole screen now.

Comment: @Rough set `height: 70%` to `video.fillWidth`

Comment: video doesn't cover the screen anymore.